# is there a way to merge a git repo into an existing directory?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, git-bash

I have a repo configured in VSTS MyRepoX.  This repo only has a readme file. I have a local VisualStudio solution that I want to include in the directory and then I need to make sure that these 2 sources are in sync for pushes and pulls. What steps can I take to do this?

Comment: Did you commit and push the changes from the existing directory to VSTS git repo successfully as the way Daniel said?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to turn your local folder into a Git repo, add a remote, and then synchronize the two.

In your local folder,

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin url-to-remote-repo
git fetch origin master
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
git pull --rebase
git push
```

I'd also recommend adding a standard Visual Studio [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) before you do any of that so that you don't get binaries/packages in your repo.

Comment: Great, this works. Can you explain the reason for the fetch and branch step? I'm new to git and I want to get a better understanding of why it was done in this case

Comment: Thanks! Recently, one of my git repos became corrupted and for some strange reason, it kept saying that the master branch wasn't born yet.

Using `fetch origin master`, `branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` and `git pull --rebase` fixed the issue for me.

Attempting to commit the untracked files first meant I had to skip that commit during the rebase.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Mann's answer works fine, but an alternate approach would be to clone the repo to a new folder, then just copy your source files into it:

```
git clone http://my.repo.url/
```

This git command will clone the repo into a new folder with the same name as the repo.  You'll want to make sure the folder your source code is in has a different folder name.

Then just copy your source files into the newly cloned folder and run the following Git commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push
```

Definitely agree that you should add a .gitignore file before the "git add ." as Daniel recommended.